# onException and onCompletion together in RouteBuilder`s route

Tags: apache-camel, onexception

I would like to use OnException & OnComplition together in one route (Camel version 2.10.0.redhat-60024):

```
from("direct:camelTestEndpoint").
            onCompletion().
                log("onCompletion1").
                log("onCompletion2").
                log("onCompletion3").
            end().
            onException(Throwable.class).
                handled(true).
                log("onException").
            end().

            log("route")
            .throwException(new RuntimeException());
```

Although it does not work as I expect.
Exception in main route causes onComplition route to stop after first processor (it is handled in PipelineHelper`s continueProcessing() method). Camel checks if exception was handled and if yes - stops the processing.

Output:

```
route
onException
onCompletion1
```

Is there I gentle way to say camel that it should skip this (without "CamelErrorHandlerHandled" property removal)?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: Hi Claus. Sorry, my bad.
2.10.0.redhat-60024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in that version of Camel.

This has been fixed by CAMEL-7707.

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7707

As a workaround you would need to manually remove those details from the exchange, in the first process in the onCompletion you do.

For example something a like

```
    // must remember some properties which we cannot use during onCompletion processing
    // as otherwise we may cause issues
    Object stop = exchange.removeProperty(Exchange.ROUTE_STOP);
    Object failureHandled = exchange.removeProperty(Exchange.FAILURE_HANDLED);
    Object caught = exchange.removeProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT);
    Object errorhandlerHandled = exchange.removeProperty(Exchange.ERRORHANDLER_HANDLED);
```

Comment: Fears were justified :)
Yeah, I`m removing "CamelErrorHandlerHandled" and it works (I do not care about failures, do not use route stop and do need exception caught).
Claus, thanks for great product support you provide.

Answer (score 0):

```
//STEP1: call Successful Route
   from("direct:Route_OnCompletion_OnSuccess")
        .onCompletion()
          .onCompleteOnly()
            .log("On Complete Passed")
            .to("direct:Route_OnSuccess")
        .end()
        .to("direct:Route_OnCompletion_OnFailure");

//STEP2: call Failure Route                
    from("direct:Route_OnCompletion_OnFailure")
        .onCompletion()           
            .onFailureOnly()    
                .log("On Complete Failed "+ body())
                .to("direct:Route_OnFailure")       
        .end() 
        .to("direct:Route_MainFlow");
```